# Waiting for Future to be Complete in HTTP GET

Tags: scala, playframework, future

I am trying to return a temperature conversion as a HTTP GET request and display it. Currently I do not think it is waiting for the future to complete. If I try and add the onComplete callback then it won't compile and complains about the async being overloaded.

```scala
def getTemperature = Action.async {
    val futureTemp = scala.concurrent.Future { convert.convertTemperature(convert.qTemperature.front) }
    futureTemp.map(i => Ok("Got result: " + i.value))
  }

def convertTemperature(cTemp:Temperature) : Future[Double] = Future {
    //If typeOfTemp is F convert it to C and vise versa
    val typeOfTemp = cTemp.typeOfTemp
    val tempVal = cTemp.tempVal

    typeOfTemp match {
      case "F" => (tempVal - 32) * 5 / 9
      case "C" => (tempVal / 5) + 32
    }
  }
```

If I return just `i` then it will show `Future(<not completed>)`
If I return the `i.value` like in the code above it will show `None`
I want it to wait and show the number value. I.e. `F, 32` will just return `0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Action.async` expects a function that returns `Future[Result]` however you are providing `Future[Future[Result]]` in the following line

```
Future { convert.convertTemperature(convert.qTemperature.front) }
```

because `convertTemperature` already returns `Future`. Try simplifying to

```
def getTemperature = Action.async {
  convert
    .convertTemperature(convert.qTemperature.front)
    .map(i => Ok(s"Got result: $i"))
}
```